# Good bitmap fonts with big sizes and unicode support

Tags: fonts

I really like bitmap fonts for programming/terminal. As far as I know there are two bitmap fonts with good unicode support:

- [Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html)
- [Fixed](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs-fonts.html)

The problem is that I have a really high resolution screen, and they're both too small. Fixed does include a large size (10x20) but it looks really bad (it's basically always bold, and bold is a different face).

Are there any other bitmap fonts with unicode support and large sizes? Terminus is the only font with a decent size but it doesn't have good unicode support. Having good coverage for mathematical symbols would be enough, since that's what I need.

Comment: Come now, moderators; bitmap fonts stay unchanged for decades.  The answers are unlikely to become outdated quickly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My [UW ttyp0](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~uwe/misc/uw-ttyp0/) has about 3000 Unicode characters, including a number of stylistic variants (plain, dotted or slashed zero, centered or raised asterisk, visible or invisble NBSP, etc.). I don't know which symbols you're looking for; math coverage is clearly not complete, but it may be sufficient for your needs. APL and Z notation are not covered, though. Sizes range from 6x11 to 11x22 in regular, bold, and some italic. Currently it's only .bdf/.pcf (that is, the X11 bitmap format); if you need .fon or some other font format, you'll have to convert it yourself (it's free software).

Comment: You font is really beautiful and useful, thanks for your work and sharing. Related to your statement about *if you need .fon*: could you provide some hints how to convert your font to .fon, please? (and name some tools, both win and nix are good). TYIA.

Comment: There is a bdf2fon tool at github, but I've never used it. If I remember correctly, fontforge can also convert to fon.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't produce a valid result. bdf2fon is composed of 2 apps: bdf2fnt and fnt2fon. When running bdf2fnt it stops with the error `can't parse line ENCODING 256`. It seems everything is limited to 255 chars. Something similar I get from FontForge when performing *Generate fonts*: a small 5kb .fon file as output with only 255 chars. Any ideas how to bypass this 255 limit? or maybe even better if a specification of the FON format could be found and I'll be able to write an app for this purpose.

Comment: According to the spec for .fnt, which can be found for instance at [http://www.undocprint.org/formats/font_formats](http://www.undocprint.org/formats/font_formats), there is indeed a hard-coded limit: It says that the character codes of the first and the last character in the font are stored as bytes (that is, 0 to 255). So fnt/fon works only for 8-bit code pages. Can you convert it to a bitmap-only .ttf using fontforge instead?

Comment: FON can use more than 255 chars for sure (at least [Terminus](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/) is one example, ~880 chars, and it also has BDF files). About *bitmap-only .ttf*: I select `(faked) MS bitmap only..`, then I get the warning `..font contains no glyphs wiht unicode encoding`, then I get a ~75kb .ttf which can't be open/used by the OS, but the font extensio tool says `Ttyp0 Medium contains 2936 glyphs and no standard kern pairs. This font includes embedded bitmaps.`

Comment: Thanks!  It is missing some characters I need but it's the best thing around anyway.

Comment: Which ones do you need in addition?

Comment: Great looking font, but looking at the .bdf file, the glyphs don't seem to be in codepoint order. e.g. `ENCODING 0` is capital 'A'. How is one meant to create the `glyphs[codepoint]` lookup?

Comment: The source bdf files use a proprietary encoding
  and have to be converted into a standard format during the
  installation process. Optionally edit VARIANTS.dat, optionally edit TARGETS.dat, then run "./configure ; make ; make install"